# Extracting value form netCDF for location and across time-range

Tags: python, pandas, netcdf, netcdf4, python-xarray

Is there a netCDF4 equaivalent of the xarray function to select values from a netCDF file for a lat lon and for a specific time-range:

```
hndl_nc.sel(time=slice(start_date, end_date)).sel(lon=lon, lat=lat, method='nearest')
```

I do not want to use cdo or nco

Comment: why not do it in xarray as you already do?. or use .values at the end to extract the data directly as a np.array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be differences based on your particular dataset, but this function like this should pull values out at specific coordinates and time slice:

```
def variable_pull(site_lat, site_lon, lat, lon, var, time_slice):
    lat_idx = (np.abs(lat-site_lat)).argmin()
    lon_idx = (np.abs(lon-site_lon)).argmin()
    return var[time_slice, lat_idx, lon_idx]
```

for a dataset opened with netCDF4 similarly to this:

```
f = ncdf.Dataset("filepath","r")
lat = f.variables['lat'][:]
lon = f.variables['lon'][:]
var = f.variables['var'][:]
f.close()
site_lat = your coordinates of interest
site_lon = your coordinates of interest
values = variable_pull(site_lat, site_lon, lat, lon, var, time_slice)
```